# Simulate click with javascript to open window in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, automation

I am trying to click in `<a>` tag in website with JavaScript but this doesn't function, when I click in this tag web page show window. I would like to do it with JavaScript.

HTML CODE is:

```
<div id="r123">
  <a class="simple-button" target="_parent" href="javascript:window('open/?id=', '123')">
    <div class="icon"/>
     <span>click</span>
   </a>
 </div>
```

I wrote this code to test it in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("r123").firstChild.click();
```

but this doesn't function.

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is : 
    document.getElementById("r123").firstElementChild.click()

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet will be to create a Javascript function that performs the task you want. Then you can make your `<a>` tag call the function, and call the same function in your JavaScript.

So you'd make a function:

```
function openNewWindow() {
    window('open/?id=', '123');
}
```

Then your `<a>` tag would be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openNewWindow()">
```

And, of course, you can call `openNewWindow` whenever you like from your other JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

you can open directly the page by clicking on the href this way:

```html
<body>

<h3>A demonstration of how to access an A element</h3>

<a id="myAnchor" href="example.com" target="_blank">Tutorials</a>

</body>
```

or you can add button that looks like href this way:

```html
<body>
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()" >Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.open("example.com");
    }
</script>
    <style>
        .btn{
            outline:none;
            text-decoration:underline; 
            color:blue;
            border:none;
            background-color:transparent;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```